# Apple TV - download unlisted app from appstore

Tags: app-store

Just a few days ago our company added an app for apple tv on review in the App Store on public distribution. After review apple said that we had to change our distribution to unlisted app distribution. I think: "Ok, it would be downloaded by the direct link". Today they approved our application and now it has a direct link to App Store. But now I find out that there is no browser on AppleTV and I could not just go to the url and download the app. Also, I couldn´t send link via AirDrop or paste it in Notes.
So the question is how I can download the unlisted app from AppleTV.
P.S. Of course I send a request to Applse Support, but they will send the answer in 2 business days... it´s too long

Comment: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This question is not about developing or developers, it´s all about how to share and download unlisted app for users

Comment: And that is very off topic for stackoverflow.com. And why do you tag your question with `swift` when you apparently know that it is wrong?

Comment: @ЕгорСоловьев did you ever figure out an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

0 Your iPad/iPhone must be logged in to the same account as the TV

1 Open the appstore link on an iPad/iPhone

e.g. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/youtube-watch-listen-stream/id544007664

2 Click purchase.

The app will install on your TV, or appear in the 'Purchased' or 'Not on This TV' section of the AppStore app.

*Note - this may take several hours*

Note, if your app is TVOS only - this will still work! You get a dialogue about how the app will install on your TV.

(I have only tested this from iPad, but am assuming the same works on iOS)